# Can the bluetooth idle threshhold be extended?

Tags: hardware, bluetooth

I use a bluetooth keyboard, and it becomes temporarily unresponsive when I don't type for a few minutes.  Once I hit a key and wait about 10 seconds, the connection becomes live again and I can resume typing.  Is there a setting that delays when bluetooth devices are considered idle?  Thanks.